# C# node graph api to use

Tags: c#, .net, graph

I need display a node graph in c# and find the short possible path(figure 10 of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289152(VS.71).aspx). What API can i use to draw out all the node and link?
Anyone can advise?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using WPF, then [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) sounds like an ideal solution for graph visualization. As for finding the shortest path between two nodes, you'll probably want to use Dijkstra's algorithm for this, which is implemented by [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) (which itself is used by Graph#).

Answer (score 0):

Note - if you directly follow the link in Will's answer you get to the correct website. If you ask Google about QuickGraph the first link is to the CodeProject site which is deprecated. Make sure you go to the CodePlex site (Will links directly to it).